# Disabling windows 7 interface shadows

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-7

Is there any method to disable the shadow under a window in my application via C#? I searched on Internet but nothing helps me...

Comment: I think this is more of a feature of Windows itself (perhaps more specifically the Aero theme).  What sort of shadow are you talking about?  Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/113804/removing-drop-shadow-from-windows-in-windows-7

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I am not at a computer, so I cannot post a printscreen right now, but I am talinkg about the Aero Theme shadow.